# Restore elasticsearch cluster onto another cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

Hello i have 3 node elasticsearch cluster ( source ) and i have snapshot called
snapshot-1 which taken from source cluster
and i have another 6 node elasticsearch cluster ( destination ) cluster

and when i restore my destinatition cluster from snapshot-1 using this command

```
curl -X POST -u elastic:321 "192.168.2.15:9200/snapshot/snapshot_repository/snapshot-1/_restore?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'

> {
> "indices": "*",
> "ignore_unavailable": true,
> "include_global_state": false,
> "rename_pattern": ".security(.+)",
> "rename_replacement": "delete_$1",
> "include_aliases": false
> }
> '
{
```

and i got this error

```
"error" : {

"root_cause" : [

  {

    "type" : "snapshot_restore_exception",

    "reason" : "[snapshot:snapshot-1 yjg/mHsYhycHQsKiEhWVhBywxQ] cannot restore index [.ilm-history-0003] because an open index with same name already exists in the cluster. Either close or delete the existing index or restore the index under a different name by providing a rename pattern and replacement name"

  }
```

so as you can see the index .ilm-history-0003 already exists in the cluster, but how can i do rename replacement for security,.ilm,.slm,.transfrom indices using only 1 rename_pattern?
like this one

`"rename_pattern": ".security(.+)",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solve it using this way

```
curl -X POST -u elastic:321 "192.168.2.15:9200/snapshot/snapshot_repository/snapshot-1/_restore?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
```

with response:

```js
{
  "indices": "*,-.slm*,-,ilm*,-.transfrom*,-security*",
  "ignore_unavailable": true,
  "include_global_state": false,
  "include_aliases": false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From my experiences the rename pattern doesn't need to be super fancy because you will probably

a) delete the index (as your renaming pattern suggests) or

b) reindex data from the restored index to new indices. In this case the naming of the restored index is insignificant.

So this is what **I** would suggest:

Use the following renaming pattern to include all indices. Again, from my experience, your first aim is to get the old data restored. After that you have to manage the reindexing etc.

```
POST /_snapshot/REPOSITORY_NAME/SNAPSHOT_NAME/_restore
{
  "indices": "*",
  "ignore_unavailable": true,
  "include_aliases": false,
  "include_global_state": false,
  "rename_pattern": "(.+)",
  "rename_replacement": "restored_$1"
}
```

This will prepend `restored_` to the actual index name resulting in the following restored indices:

- restored_security
- restored_.ilm*
- restored_.slm*
- restored_.transfrom*

I hope I could help you.